# Foreign key to part of primary key's table

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with this tables **Conversion** and **Client** I want to create relation between this tables 
so ID_Send in **Conversion** Reference to ID in **Client** 
and ID_Receive in **Conversion** Reference to ID in **Client**

```
create table Conversion(ID_Send int ,
                        ID_Receive int ,
                        [Time] datetime,
                        [Message] varchar(2048),
                        primary key(ID_Send,ID_Receive,[Time])
                        )

create table Client (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
                    [First name] varchar(500) not null,
                    [Last Name]varchar(500) not null,
                    [Birth day] datetime,
                    Gender bit not null,
                    Country  varchar(200)not null,
                    City varchar(200) ,
                    [Language] varchar(200)not null, 
                    [Chat name] varchar(500)not null ,
                    [Password] varchar (500)not null,
                    --foreign key(ID) REFERENCES Conversion (ID_Send)--there is an error 
                    )
```

Comment: http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Foreign-key-referencing-only-part-of-composite-primary-key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motazz, there can be only one Primary key in a table like you have in the Client table. to get rid of the error:

1st create the Client table, 
2nd replace the code for Conversion with:

```
create table Conversion(ID_Send int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Client(ID),
                    ID_Receive int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Client(ID),
                    [Time] datetime,
                    [Message] varchar(2048),
                    primary key(ID_Send,ID_Receive,[Time])
                    )
```

Comment: Agree with this except you seem to imply that the OP needs to drop the tables and recreate them in the correct order solely to add foreign key constraints which they didn't manage to add the first time. Instead, they can simply use  `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` statement(s) to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a compound primary key (made up of mulitple columns), all your foreign keys also **must** use **all columns** of the PK to reference that table.

After all : how else would you be able to make a clear, deterministic reference from a child table to the parent? Only if you use the columns that **uniquely identify** one row in the parent table does this work.

The only workaround would be to put a UNIQUE index on the `ID_Send` and `ID_Receive` columns in your parent table and then reference that unique index.

But then the question is: if those values are unique - why isn't one of those columns alone your primary key??